# Controller reading Chinese as parameters Error 400

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-400

So I have a controller that reads in a parameter to determine which page to display.
the controller uses a model to retrieve information from the database (articles).

```
<?php if ( ! defined(‘BASEPATH’)) exit(‘No direct script access allowed’);

class Articles extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct(); 
$this->load->model('ArtModel');
}

public function index($artTitle){ 
$data['query'] = $this->ArtModel->get_article(urldecode($artTitle));
$this->load->view('inc/header',$data);
$this->load->view('articles',$data);
$this->load->view('inc/footer'); 
}
}
```

the Decode URL is there so that the correct information gets sent to the database. And all this works locally. however when I uploaded it to my website, I kept getting a 400, but if the input parameter ($artTitle) are english characters, the pages displays normally.

can anyone tell me why this doesnt work with Chinese characters?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a data charset issue. Check & update following line of code in application/config/database.php

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Hope this might work.